# Unable to copy more than 15 columns with Columns().Copy

Tags: vba, excel

```
With ws
    'TROUBLE MAKER BELOW
    'CRIMS Print Header
    .Rows("1:6").Delete
    .Cells.AutoFilter
    .Cells.ClearFormats
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("A1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("B1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("C1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("D1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("E1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("F1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("G1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("H1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("I1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("J1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("K1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("L1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("M1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("N1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("O1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("P1")
    .Columns(X).Copy activeWB.Sheets("SHEET NAME").Range("Q1")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

This is a snippet of my code, As you can see it's a simple logic thingy, copying of columns. But faced an issue where I can't copy any columns above P... Which means, P, Q , R and so on....

But weird thing here is that, if i run my VBA Excel Macro on debug, step into and let it run. it works fine. Any hope of having it work? Really stuck with this...

Much thanks and appreciated.

Comment: If the ranges are non-contiguous then use something like `union(.Columns(X), .Columns(GX))`.copy and cycle the destination. Without a destination, it is difficult to determine what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jeeped Hey there. My objective is just to copy them in columns over from another sheet in another workbook. That's all. Is there any other way?

Comment: `But weird thing here is that, if i run my VBA Excel Macro on debug, step into and let it run. it works fine.` That means your application needs more time to do the operation. Seems liek there is lot of data. Please use `DoEvents` after every `Paste`

Comment: You seem to have an extra `)` on the line copying to `O1`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yea, i know. did a typo was removing some sensitive stuffs.

Comment: @SiddharthRout When my process is done, it will prompt a message. So technically i should be able to view it once it says complete. And yes, there's quite a lot of data. But i don't think it's that much to clog up the code i wrote. There's about 3000 rows. and 61 columns. xD but im only selecting a few columns, namely the above number of columns.

Comment: did you try what i suggested?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Placed it below the "...End With"

Didn't work. Column is still missing.

Comment: Please read my first comment again :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Am lost, But the whole chunk is considered to be a line of code, no? I can just place DoEvents in between them?

Apologies, never had any VB training. Im basically doing a crashcourse. xD

Comment: No the whole chunk consists of different rows. I wanna check something.. Type `DoEvents` after every line which starts with `.Columns(X).Copy....` and then run the code.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yea i did, nothing came up still. Am right now trying to debug step by step using msgBox alongside DoEvents, in every line to see where it got lost.

Comment: kool. That would help

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't really an Answer for my error. But apparently, some other methods utilized the 3 last few rows to do filtering. As the Codes are done by another group of peeps, it's hard for me to drill down the problem...

But after countless debugging and handful strands of hair dropping, i found out that the method blanked out 3 columns... So what I did was that i hide the few columns that was played by other method and use the other available columns.
It is not related to the copy function nor was it related to processing time.